# Какое отличие call() от обычного вызова?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Расскажите пожалуйста, какое отличие `call()` от обычного вызова?

```
function product (name) {
   console.log(name)
}

function res (fn) {
   fn.call(“test”);
   // ведь можно так
   //fn(“test”);
}
```

Comment: Туда контекст обычно передается. [Применение «func.call» для передачи контекста](https://learn.javascript.ru/call-apply-decorators#primenenie-func-call-dlya-peredachi-konteksta)